# React component - this.setState skips after first iteration

Tags: reactjs

Setting this.setState inside a for loop skips after the first iteration. There is a switch statement inside for loop but it doesn't traverse all items.

eg:-

```
 var items=[{key:"test",val:"hi"},{key:"test1",val:"hello"}];

    for(let item in items){
        console.log(items[item].key);
        console.log(items[item]["key"]);
        switch(items[item].key){
           case "test" : {
               console.log(items[item].val);
                        this.setState({testvar:items[item].val});
                        break;
                        }
              case "test1" : {
                        console.log(items[item].val);
                        this.setState({test1var:items[item].val});
                        break;
                        }

        }
   }
```

Comment: can you show us your `items` array?

Comment: My bad: correcting the loop:

Comment: `var items=[{key:"test",val:"hi"},{key:"test1",val:"hello"}];
  
  for(let item in items){
   console.log(items[item].key);
   console.log(items[item]["key"]);
   switch(items[item].key){
      case "test" : {
       console.log(items[item].val);
       this.setState({testvar:items[item].val});
       break;
       }
      case "test1" : {
     console.log(items[item].val);
       this.setState({test1var:items[item].val});
       break;
       }
    
   }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this.setState` will trigger a re-render of your component and a garbage clean-up of your for loop.  You need to track all of the changes and call `setState` once.